# Google Maps – Keep Icon, Infowindow, and Map Layer centered

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events, window-resize

How can I use Javascript and CSS to keep my Google Maps Icon, Infowindow, and Map Layer centered? I've seen instances where the icon stays centered but the map layer does not... I want to be able to set my map's width to 100% so that it fills up the entire width of the browser window, while always keeping the map icon, infowindow, and map layer centered.

Example if someone resizes their browser from 1500px wide to say 800px wide the map icon, infowindow, and map layer should stay centered at all times.

Listed below is my working html, Javascript, and CSS for my current map... so given this code how would I make the correct adjustments to keep my map icon, infowindow, and map background layer centered.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="map-wrapper"> 
    <div id="map-canvas" data-lat="40.7484404" data-lng="-73.9856554" data-address="Empire+State+Bldg,+350+5th+Ave,+New+York,+NY+10118+United+States"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var mapID = document.getElementById('map-canvas');

var mapDataLat = mapID.getAttribute('data-lat');
var mapDataLng = mapID.getAttribute('data-lng');
var mapDataAddress = mapID.getAttribute('data-address');

function initialize() {


    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        zoom: 14,
        zoomControl: false,
        panControl: true,
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.DEFAULT
        },
        streetViewControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(mapDataLat, mapDataLng)
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

    var infoContent = '<div class="window-content"><h4>Empire State Building</h4><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/' + mbDataMBAddress + '" target="_blank">Directions</a></p></div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: infoContent
    });

    var icon = {
        path: 'M16.5,51s-16.5-25.119-16.5-34.327c0-9.2082,7.3873-16.673,16.5-16.673,9.113,0,16.5,7.4648,16.5,16.673,0,9.208-16.5,34.327-16.5,34.327zm0-27.462c3.7523,0,6.7941-3.0737,6.7941-6.8654,0-3.7916-3.0418-6.8654-6.7941-6.8654s-6.7941,3.0737-6.7941,6.8654c0,3.7916,3.0418,6.8654,6.7941,6.8654z',
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(16.5, 51),
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.6,
        strokeWeight: 0,
        scale: 0.66
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapDataLat, mapDataLng),
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: 'marker'
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**CSS:**

```
#map-canvas {
  min-width: 300px; /* I would want to remove this, so width is set to 100% */
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#map-canvas img {
  max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "map background layer centered"?

Comment: I mean the actual map layer that the icon and infowindow sit on...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register a DOM listener to center your map when the window is resized.

For example:

```
// Define a global center variable
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(mapDataLat, mapDataLng);
```

Then in your `initialize` function, register the listener

```
// Listen for window resize event
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', centerMap);
```

Then just create a function that will center the map to its original position

```
function centerMap() {

    map.setCenter(center);
}
```

Or if you don't need a specific function for that, you can just do:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {

    map.setCenter(center);
});
```

Comment: Hey @MrUpsidown using your suggestion I was able to refactor my code and keep the map centered at all times... however, rather then creating a new function, I simply called the resize event on the `initialize` function itself before the load event... thanks for the push in the right direction.

Comment: Read my other comment. This is overkill. No need to recreate the whole thing. Just center your map and that's it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the correct/refactored Javascript code to keep the map's icon and background map layer centered at all times...

```
var mapID = document.getElementById('map-canvas');

var mapDataLat = mapID.getAttribute('data-lat');
var mapDataLng = mapID.getAttribute('data-lng');
var mapDataAddress = mapID.getAttribute('data-address');

function initialize() {


    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        zoom: 14,
        zoomControl: false,
        panControl: true,
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.DEFAULT
        },
        streetViewControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(mapDataLat, mapDataLng)
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

    var infoContent = '<div class="window-content"><h4>Empire State Building</h4><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/' + mbDataMBAddress + '" target="_blank">Directions</a></p></div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: infoContent
    });

    var icon = {
        path: 'M16.5,51s-16.5-25.119-16.5-34.327c0-9.2082,7.3873-16.673,16.5-16.673,9.113,0,16.5,7.4648,16.5,16.673,0,9.208-16.5,34.327-16.5,34.327zm0-27.462c3.7523,0,6.7941-3.0737,6.7941-6.8654,0-3.7916-3.0418-6.8654-6.7941-6.8654s-6.7941,3.0737-6.7941,6.8654c0,3.7916,3.0418,6.8654,6.7941,6.8654z',
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(16.5, 51),
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.6,
        strokeWeight: 0,
        scale: 0.66
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapDataLat, mapDataLng),
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: 'marker'
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', initialize); // This is the key
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: No. Please look at my answer. You don't want to initialize your map every time the window is resized. You only want to center it.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, as the above code works correctly... that being said, @MrUpsidown I experimented with your code and the map wouldn't render... could you please provide what your example code looks like with my initial code example?